# Adding NSProgressIndicators to an NSOutlineView subclass

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview, nsprogressindicator, pxsourcelist

I'm using a heavily modified version of the fantastic [PXSourceList](https://github.com/Perspx/PXSourceList/) control to emulate other popular OS X source lists. Unfortunately I've run into some issues while attempting to add NSProgressIndicator's to rows within said source list.

PXSourceList acts as a subclass of the standard NSOutlineView control and comes packaged with an example SourceListItem class (a skeletal NSObject subclass). Rendering of the PXSourceList and its SourceListItem's is handled in PXSourceList's `drawRow:clipRect:` method, which is the source of my problem.

I'm trying to find the best way of allowing each SourceListItem to optionally display an NSProgressIndicator. Instinct tells me I should be creating a custom cell, but I'm unsure as to how I should optimally implement a decent solution.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great example in the Apple Sample code that does this (alas not using PXSourceList).

[Animated TableView Sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AnimatedTableView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008863)

Also look at this answer for commentary and links to some sample code: 
[How to display indeterminate NSProgressIndicator in the NSOutlineView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058639/how-to-display-indeterminate-nsprogressindicator-in-the-nsoutlineview)

In essence, as their is no NSProgressIndicatorCell class, you need to create a subview containing an NSProgressIndicatorView and display it at the appropriate row in your tableview.